# Are questions about fanfics on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are fan-fics fair game for this site?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251/are-fan-fics-fair-game-for-this-site)

Are questions about fanfics based on SF&F works on topic?

If so, are story identification questions about fanfics based on SF&F works on topic?

Comment: I don't know that we've ever restricted ourselves to published works only, so I don't see why not.

Comment: @IanPugsley: How do you define published?  Technically, the act of printing up a number of copies and selling them at a con is publishing, and so is just posting it online for free.

Comment: @TangoOversway good point.  My point is that we should allow these anyway, so why bother defining it? :)

Answer (score 4):

Have at it.

I guess that's too short for an answer. But I really see no reason why not.

Comment: I have a number of long HP fics (novel length) that Ir ead and can't seem to find anymore. So I'll ask :)