# Why are we downvoting this perfectly good story ID question (that happens to involve weird fanfic)?

Tags: discussion, voting

We established [quite a while ago](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251/are-fan-fics-fair-game-for-this-site) that fanfiction is on-topic.  I would therefore expect that people who don't want to see fanfic questions would just ignore the [fan-fiction](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fan-fiction) tag and move on.

About a week ago, someone asked this story-ID question:

[Harry Potter Fanfic where Harry is impregnated by Draco](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/161160/harry-potter-fanfic-where-harry-is-impregnated-by-draco)

The question is clear, gives numerous highly-specific details about the story, and is rather unlikely to match more than one story exactly (though I grant that it will superficially match quite a few stories, because this plot is apparently a thing in the *Harry Potter* fandom).

At the time of writing, it's sitting at +7/-6.  I appreciate that this is not the kind of question that some of us are here to answer.  However, as mentioned above, those people can easily ignore the fanfic tag.

**Am I missing something, or are these downvotes undeserved?**

Comment: I happen to agree. It deserves all the funny comments it's getting, but not the downvotes.

Comment: Probaby because it looks semi-pornographic

Comment: I'm more disturbed by the upvotes on a wrong answer.

Comment: @ibid - It's not the correct answer, but it also excludes that story, and hence is "useful".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> We established quite a while ago that fanfiction is on-topic.

Yes. And that's probably why the question has not received any close votes at this time.

> are these downvotes undeserved?

Whether or not the post *deserves* downvotes is a matter of opinion. Voting is in the eye of the beholder. It is well-established on the Stack Exchange network that voting is totally at the discretion of the user casting the vote, as long as the vote is cast based on the *content* of the post (as opposed to the *user* who posted it -- e.g. you can't upvote your buddy's posts just because he's your buddy).

Maybe the downvoters disliked the [wall of text](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/161160/1) in the first revision of the post. Maybe the downvoters don't like questions about fan fiction that contradicts canon. Maybe the downvoters don't like the subject of the fan fiction the post is asking about. Who knows?

Comment: I was sort-of OK with Harry being pregnant ("It happens with wizards sometimes"), but when he had to _labour_ instead of using some magik, I was genuinely disappointed.

Comment: Accepted, but somewhat reluctantly, because I still don't see how the Harry Potter question is that much weirder than, say, [robots taking their skin off, having sex, and then getting eaten by bugs](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/161558/comic-book-short-story-where-a-couple-of-robots-take-off-their-metal-skin-and-ge).  But oh well, people are inconsistent.

Comment: @Kevin I'd say because HP fanfics are particularly notorious for being ridiculous in their nature. Robots, on the other hand, can do anything they want.