# Should we allow fan-fiction identification?

Tags: discussion, scope, story-identification

I like [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification). While the questions are sometimes bad, some are really well written and fun to look for. However, fan-fiction identifications are...subpar most of the time. Many are just one line or two, and they tend to be badly written. Additionally, a lot of them are just Drarry fan fictions with one of two or so plots (“Harry is turning into a baby” is very common).

**Why do we allow this category of frequently terrible questions? Should we reconsider this?**

Comment: I've marked this as a dupe since it seems you weren't aware of the previous discussions about this (TL;DR: we don't have to *like* them, but there's no reason to declare them *off-topic*). If you really want to reopen the discussion (as in "I know these have always been on-topic per previous consensus, but should we change the scope in 2019 because xyz"), I can reopen it.

Comment: One question: are the really bad fanfic-ID questions generally upvoted a lot? If not, then we can let the downvotes do their work without needing to use close votes.

Comment: @Randal'Thor The dupe link points to another dupe, not to the question with the actual answer.

Comment: The original being this one: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251/are-fan-fics-fair-game-for-this-site

Comment: I am voting to re-open so that this can be closed as a dupe of [this](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/251/102999), which **has answers** unlike the other question.