# Are we really here to solve problems?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-faq

The [FAQ](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) says:

> "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on **actual problems that you face**."

Really? Are we only meant to ask questions about problems we face?

Sounds like a copy / paste from another Stack Exchange site.

**Update:** in light of the comments below, I should add that I don't have a problem with the existence of the site (quite the opposite), just with the *wording of the FAQ*. Can we change that wording?

Comment: Good point, also since this is Science Fiction and Fantasy there are going to be questions that don't have a perfect answer with a reference artical behind it - if all the questions that get asked can just be found with a 3 minute google search what is the point of this site?

Comment: And also: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/389/sci-fi-fantasy-not-a-how-to-is-this-a-problem

Comment: IIUC everything under the line is the same on every StackExchange site (http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/549/what-should-our-faq-contain).  So it is a 'copy and paste' in a way, yes.

Comment: @Gilles: not a duplicate, I want to change the FAQ, hence the update to my question.

Comment: @Wikis Oh, I see. Even with your edit, that's not clear at all. Well, ok then, but this part is common to all SE sites, so don't hold your breath.

Comment: Now on Meta.SO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164436/is-there-a-rule-of-thumb-for-objective-questions-asked-out-of-curiosity

Answer (score 9):

It depend of your definition of problem :

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem)

> A problem is an obstacle, impediment, difficulty or challenge, or any situation that invites resolution; the resolution of which is recognized as a solution or contribution toward a known purpose or goal. A problem implies a desired outcome coupled with an apparent deficiency, doubt or inconsistency that prevents the outcome from taking place.

[dictionary.reference](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/problem)

> prob·lem noun
>    1. any question or matter involving doubt, uncertainty, or difficulty.
>    2. a question proposed for solution or discussion.
>    3. Mathematics. a statement requiring a solution, usually by means of a mathematical operation or geometric construction.

So, if you definition is more in the line of Wikipedia, no we don't *really* solve any problem. But if you take it in the line of dictionary.reference, we solve some. Those problems are less practical than, say [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), [cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/) or [home improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/). They are also less *useful* since they are about imaginary universes. But they are still problems.

Peoples are puzzled by all the information that is available about Sci-Fi and Fantasy. Accessing, filtering and extracting the meaningful information is the real problem, that's why we are here.

Answer (score 2):

Borrowed from [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/399/108).

Using the FAQ on-topic categories:

- Plot, character, or setting explanations: my problem is that I don't understand why something happened.
- Historical context: my problem is that I don't understand how this work fits into real-world history.
- Behind-the-scenes and fandom information: my problem is I don't know how to get the best out of a conference, my problem is I don't know how to contact an author.
- Story identification: my problem is that I cannot find this work that I remember loving.
- Franchise/series reading or viewing order: my problem is that I don't know what order it would be best to consume these in.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. However, the generic problem we are trying to solve here - which was very clearly hashed out on this meta question: " [Is "I am curious about X" sufficient justification for asking questions on SFF.SE?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2865/is-i-am-curious-about-x-sufficient-justification-for-asking-questions-on-sff-s) ", is:

> "I'm curious" about XYZ topic/detail and need explanation.

THAT is considered a fully sufficient problem as far as this sites purpose is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

As a newer user of the site I have already concluded that the answer is yes or no.

There seem to be several types of answers:

- Where the questioner asks a question that they don't know the answer
  to but there is a verifiable answer.
- There is a question with a, likely, 'in-universe' answer based on
  reasoned inference.
- there is a question where there is no realistic 'in-universe' answer 
  to but the most elaborate conjecture is still favored over the,
  frowned upon, answer of 'there is no real answer other than the
  creator of the subject matter needed a plot device.
- There is a question which request an 'out-universe' explanation to
  answer an 'in-universe' question; where, despite the fact that an
  'out-universe' answer might be impossible, even the most ridiculous
  'in-universe' answer is still favored over the answer of, "it's not
  possible."

I believe the main point of the site is not to answer questions but to maintain the fantasy by any means necessary (which is more fun!)