# Can we please fix the About page to remove "actual problem" and "practical" wording?

Tags: discussion, scope, closing-questions

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/about

> **Get answers to **practical**, detailed questions**
>
> Focus on questions about an **actual problem** you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do.

These seem to be generic wordings from standard SE sites; and are WRONG for SFF as per Meta consensus (11/-1 on the question, 13/0 on the only answer):

[Is "I am curious about X" sufficient justification for asking questions on SFF.SE?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2865/is-i-am-curious-about-x-sufficient-justification-for-asking-questions-on-sff-s/2869)

> I have always felt that the "actual problems that you face" clause is generally a poor fit for SciFi and a few other SE sites.
>   I understand the reason for it, but I just feel that we're far enough from the topics of the sites where it originated that its value is diluted for us.
>   So I'd say that yes, "I'm curious" is sufficient justification for asking a question, as far as that specific clause goes.

Comment: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1380/are-we-really-here-to-solve-problems

Comment: "I'm curious" is an actual problem that we've all faced.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We (mods) can change the "Ask about" and "Don't ask about" lists, but not the title "Get answers to practical, detailed question" or the paragraphs on the left. If you come up with a good enough alternative, we will bring it up with the team, but I think it's unlikely they'll actually change it.

Comment: Paging @Beofett